# Getting segmentation error in linked list in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>

#define SIZE 50

struct studentReportCard
{
    char *name;
    int class;
    int roll;
    long long int phno;
    float *marks;
    float total;
    float totalPer;
    struct studentReportCard *next;
};

typedef struct studentReportCard node;

void createReportCard(node *list)
{
    int i=0,choice;
    while(1)
    {   
        i++;
        printf("Press the following buttons to perform the specified function:\n");
        printf("\t1 - Create a report card for Student %d.\n\t2 - Stop creating any additional report     cards.\n",i);
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        getchar();
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                list->name=(char *)malloc(SIZE*sizeof(char));
                list->marks=(float *)malloc(3*sizeof(float));
                printf("Insert the name of the student %d:\n",i);
                fgets(list->name,SIZE,stdin);
                list->name[strcspn(list->name,"\n")]='\0';
                printf("Insert the class,roll number and phone number of %s respectively: ",list->name);
                scanf("%d %d %lld",&(list->class),&(list->roll),&(list->phno));
                printf("Enter the marks awarded to %s in Physics, Chemistry and Mathematics respectively: ",list->name);
                scanf("%f %f %f",&(list->marks[0]),&(list->marks[1]),&(list->marks[2]));
                list->total=list->marks[0]+list->marks[1]+list->marks[2];
                list->totalPer=(list->total)/3.0f;
                list->next=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
                if(list->name==NULL||list->marks==NULL||list->next==NULL)
                {
                    printf("Memory Allocation Failed! Stoping the creation of new report cards...\n");
                    return;
                }
                list=list->next;
                break;
            case 2:
                list->next=NULL;
                return;
            default:
                printf("Please enter a valid option!\n");
        }
    }
}

void printReportCard(node *list)
{
    if(list->next==NULL)
    {
        printf("The list is empty.\n");
        return;
    }
    while(list->next!=NULL)
    {
        printf("\n\n");
        printf("Name of the student: %s\n",list->name);
        printf("Class: %d\n",list->class);
        printf("Roll Number: %d\n",list->roll);
        printf("Phone Number: %lld\n",list->phno);
        printf("Marks awarded in Physics = %.2f/100\n",list->marks[0]);
        printf("Marks awarded in Chemistry = %.2f/100\n",list->marks[1]);
        printf("Marks awarded in Mathematics = %.2f/100\n",list->marks[2]);
        printf("Total marks awarded = %.2f/300\n",list->total);
        printf("Total Percentage: %.2f%%\n",list->totalPer);
        list=list->next;
    }
    return;
}

void countReportCard(node *list)
{
    int count=0;
    while(list->next!=NULL)
    {
        count++;
        list=list->next;
    }
    if(count==0)
        printf("There are no report cards made.\n");
    else
        printf("%d report cards have been made so far.\n",count);
}

void freeMemory(node *list)
{
    while(list->next!=NULL)
    {
        free(list->name);
        free(list->marks);
        node *temp=list;
        list=list->next;
        free(temp);
    }
}
void insertion(node **list)
{
    int choice;
    node *temp;
    node *newNode=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    newNode->name=(char *)malloc(SIZE*sizeof(char));
    newNode->marks=(float *)malloc(3*sizeof(float));
    printf("Insert the name of the student:\n");
    fgets(newNode->name,SIZE,stdin);
    newNode->name[strcspn(newNode->name,"\n")]='\0';
    printf("Insert the class,roll number and phone number of %s respectively: ",newNode->name);
    scanf("%d %d %lld",&(newNode->class),&(newNode->roll),&(newNode->phno));
    printf("Enter the marks awarded to %s in Physics, Chemistry and Mathematics respectively: ",newNode->name);
    scanf("%f %f %f",&(newNode->marks[0]),&(newNode->marks[1]),&(newNode->marks[2]));
    newNode->total=newNode->marks[0]+newNode->marks[1]+newNode->marks[2];
    newNode->totalPer=(newNode->total)/3.0f;
    printf("Press the following buttons to perform the specified function:\n");
    printf("\t1 - Insert at the beginning of the list.\n\t2 - Insert at the end of the list.\n");
    printf("\t3 - Insert after a particular report card in the list.\n\t4 - Insert before a particular report card in the list.\n");
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1:
            newNode->next=*list;
            *list=newNode;
            break;
        case 2:
            if(*list==NULL)
            {
                *list=newNode;
                return;
            }
            temp=*list;
            newNode->next=NULL;
            while(temp->next!=NULL)
                temp=temp->next;
            temp->next=newNode;
            break;
            
    }
    return;
}
int main(void)
{
    int choice;
    node *head=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    createReportCard(head);
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Press the buttons below to perform the specified function:\n");
        printf("\t1 - Print the list of report cards.\n\t2 - Count the number of report cards made.\n\t3 - Insert a new report card in the existing list of report.\n\t4 - Reset the list of report cards.\n\t5 - Exit the program.\n");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        getchar();
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                printReportCard(head);
                break;
            case 2:
                countReportCard(head);
                break;
            case 3:
                insertion(&head);
                break;
            case 4:
                freeMemory(head);
                head=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
                createReportCard(head);
                break;
            case 5:
                freeMemory(head);
                return 0;
            default:
                printf("Please enter a valid option!\n");

        }
    }
}
```

I cant understand why it is giving me segmentation error. It is working fine when I add a new node at the beginning of the list but it is giving me a segmentation error when i try to add a node at the end of the linked list. The compiler is pointing me to a specific line in stdio.h when it happens:
__retval = __mingw_vfprintf( stdout, __format, __local_argv );
Please help me. Oh and dont worry about the incomplete switch case in the insertion function. I will complete it later when i solve this problem. Keep in mind that i am a beginner. I just learned insertion in linked list today. Therefore i decided to make this program today trying to implement what i learnt today. Oh and i use visual studio code btw.

Comment: OT: don't use integers to store "numbers" that are actually strings. My phone number begins with a `0`, some are with `00` and you cannot recover those leading zeros from an integer variable. In some places phone numbers are given by alphabet, like catchy.

Comment: ok i understand. Thank you for the tip @WeatherVane but what about my other problem? can you look into it?

Comment: It seems to be that your program has lots of input and output, which is likely where the problem is. I'd suggest as a first step to print out user input / output to see what's happening in the program. From there, you can add i/o guards, like making sure that the program can't scan a value over a certain threshold.

Comment: You don't set `head->next = NULL;`

Comment: If your `name` field will also be dynamically allocated to `SIZE`, why not simply declare it as an array? `char name[SIZE];`

Comment: @Chris Because i wanted to implement dynamic memory allocation as much as possible.

Comment: You shouldn't post your whole code on stackoverflow. Keep only what's necessary to the post. It's called a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help people answering you, and in doing so you might also find the answer to your question yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 50

struct report_card
{
    char name[SIZE];
    char phno[SIZE];
    int class;
    int roll;
    float marks[3];
    float total;
    float totalPercent;
    struct report_card *next;
};

typedef struct report_card node;

node *head=NULL,*temp,*newNode;

void createNode()
{
    getchar();
    newNode=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    printf("Enter the name of the student:\n");
    fgets(newNode->name,SIZE,stdin);
    newNode->name[strcspn(newNode->name,"\n")]='\0';
    printf("Enter the phone number of %s:\n",newNode->name);
    fgets(newNode->phno,SIZE,stdin);
    newNode->phno[strcspn(newNode->phno,"\n")]='\0';
    printf("Enter the class and roll number of %s: ",newNode->name);
    scanf("%d %d",&(newNode->class),&(newNode->roll));
    printf("Enter the marks awarded to %s in Physics,Chemistry and Mathematics respectively: ");
    scanf("%f %f %f",&(newNode->marks[0]),&(newNode->marks[1]),&(newNode->marks[2]));
    newNode->total=newNode->marks[0]+newNode->marks[1]+newNode->marks[2];
    newNode->totalPercent=newNode->total/3.0f;
    newNode->next=NULL;
}

void createLinkedList()
{
    int i=0,choice;
    do
    {
        i++;
        printf("Press the buttons below to perform the specified functions:\n");
        printf("\t1 - Create node %d.\n\t2 - Stop creating nodes.\n",i);
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                createNode();
                if(head==NULL)
                    head=temp=newNode;
                else
                {
                    temp->next=newNode;
                    temp=newNode; 
                }
            break;
            case 2:
                return;
            default:
                printf("Please enter a valid option!\n");
        }
    }while(choice!=2);
}

void printLinkedList()
{
    if(head==NULL)
        printf("The list is empty.\n");
    else
    {
        temp=head;
        while(temp!=NULL)
        {
            printf("\n\n");
            printf("Name of the student: %s\n",temp->name);
            printf("Phone number of the %s: %s\n",temp->name,temp->phno);
            printf("Class: %d\n",temp->class);
            printf("Roll number: %d\n",temp->roll);
            printf("Marks in Physics: %.2f\n",temp->marks[0]);
            printf("Marks in Chemistry: %.2f\n",temp->marks[1]);
            printf("Marks in Mathematics: %.2f\n",temp->marks[2]);
            printf("Total marks out of 300: %.2f\n",temp->total);
            printf("Total percentage: %.2f%%",temp->totalPercent);
            printf("\n\n");
            temp=temp->next;
        }
    }
}

int countNodes()
{
    int count=0;
    temp=head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        count++;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    return count;
}

void insertAtTheBeginning()
{
    newNode->next=head;
    head=newNode;
}

void insertAtTheEnd()
{
    temp=head;
    while(temp->next!=NULL)
        temp=temp->next;
    temp->next=newNode;
}

void insertAfterTheSpecifiedNode()
{
    int count,pos,i;
    count=countNodes();
    printf("There are currently %d nodes in the linked list.\n",count);
    printf("Enter after which position do you want to insert the node:\n(The position must be greater than zero and also must be lesser than equal to the total number of nodes in the linked list)\n");
    scanf("%d",&pos);
    while(pos>count||pos<=0)
    {
        printf("Please enter a valid position:\n(The position must be greater than zero and also must be lesser than equal to the total number of nodes in the linked list)\n");
        scanf("%d",&pos);
    }
    if(pos==count)
        insertAtTheEnd();
    else
    {
        temp=head;
        for(i=1;i<pos;i++)
            temp=temp->next;
        newNode->next=temp->next;
        temp->next=newNode;
    }
    printf("The node is inserted after position %d\n",pos);
}

void insertBeforeTheSpecifiedNode()
{
    int count,pos,i;
    count=countNodes();
    printf("There are currently %d nodes in the linked list.\n",count);
    printf("Enter before which position do you want to insert the node:\n(The position must be greater than zero and also must be lesser than equal to the total number of nodes in the linked list)\n");
    scanf("%d",&pos);
    while(pos>count||pos<=0)
    {
        printf("Please enter a valid position:\n(The position must be greater than zero and also must be lesser than equal to the total number of nodes in the linked list)\n");
        scanf("%d",&pos);
    }
    if(pos==1)
        insertAtTheBeginning();
    else
    {
        temp=head;
        for(i=1;i<pos-1;i++)
            temp=temp->next;
        newNode->next=temp->next;
        temp->next=newNode;
    }
    printf("The node is inserted before position %d\n",pos);
}

void insertion()
{
    int choice;
    createNode();
    do
    {
        printf("\n\nPress the following buttons to perform the specified functions:\n");
        printf("\t1 - Insert at the beginning of the list.\n\t2 - Insert at the end of the list.\n\t3 - Insert after a particular node.\n\t4 - Insert before a particular node.\n");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        if(head==NULL&&choice>=1&&choice<=4)
        {
            head=newNode;
            return;
        }
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                insertAtTheBeginning();
                break;
            case 2:
                insertAtTheEnd();
                break;
            case 3:
                insertAfterTheSpecifiedNode();
                break;
            case 4:
                insertBeforeTheSpecifiedNode();
                break;
            default:
                printf("Please enter a valid option!\n");
        }
    }while(choice<1||choice>4);
}

void resetLinkedList()
{
    while(head!=NULL)
    {
        temp=head;
        free(temp);
        head=head->next;
    }
    head=NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    int choice,count;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("\n\nPress the following buttons to perform the specified functions:\n");
        printf("\t1 - Create a linked list.\n\t2 - Print the current linked list.\n\t3 - Count the current number of nodes of the linked list.\n\t4 - Insert a node in the existing linked list.\n\t5 - Reset the linked list.\n\t6 - Exit the program.\n");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                createLinkedList();
                break;
            case 2:
                printLinkedList();
                break;
            case 3:
                count=countNodes();
                if(head=NULL)
                    printf("The list is empty.\n");
                else
                    printf("The list currently contains %d nodes.\n",count);
                break;
            case 4:
                insertion();
                break;
            case 5:
                resetLinkedList();
                printf("The list has been reset.\n");
                break;
            case 6:
                resetLinkedList();
                printf("Exiting the program...\n");
                return 0;
                break;
            default:
                printf("Please enter a valid option!\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you guys for your valuable feedbacks. I managed to solve the problem all on my own. And I have also applied some of your suggestions in my program. Thanks for everything.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).